# Convergence of alternating partial sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider a partial sum of the kind $\sum_{k=0}^C (-1)^{k+C} f(k,C)$, where $C$ is positive and $f(k,C)$ is a non-negative continuous function that converges monotonically to $0$ as $C\to +\infty$. How does one study the limit for $C\to +\infty$ of this partial sum? I wonder if the alternating series test still holds, given that the argument of the summation also depends on $C$.

Comment: Are sure that it's not supposed to be that f(k, C) converges as k -> infinity? Seems more sensible (with C some constant).

Comment: May be help you. Let $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k+n} f(k,n)$, then
$$S_1=-f(0,1)+f(1,1)$$
$$S_2=f(0,2)-f(1,2)+f(2,2)$$
$$S_3=-f(0,3)+f(1,3)-f(2,3)+f(3,3)$$
and so you can write 
$$S_1+S_2+...+S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^{i+1} f(0,i)+\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1} f(1,i)+...+\sum_{i=n}^n (-1)^{i+1} f(n,i)$$
For every natural $k$, define $A(k,n)=\sum_{i=k}^n (-1)^{i+1} f(k,i)$, now the alternating series test implies that $A(k,n)$ converges.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: yes it is C, not k to go to infinity.